# How to dynamically add a navbar to a jQuery Mobile application

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

How can I dynamically add a navbar to my jquery mobile application?  From javascript I want to be able to add the navbar elements to the dom and then have them parsed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that I could add the element to the DOM however I wanted, and then call .navbar() on the element and it would perform the navbar parsing.

For instance I could use

```
var myNavBar = $('div', {
    'data-role':'navbar',
    'html':'<ul><li><a id="some">First</a></li></ul>'
}).appendTo(myPage).navbar();
```

Comment: Figured I'd post this up so others could see, as it was something I couldn't find around but figured out from other StackOverflow questions.

Comment: Ah, then you should [accept your own answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2800/should-i-ask-questions-i-already-know-the-answer-to-and-answer-them-myself) (when the site lets you :).

Comment: That's adding a whole navbar. Did you find a way to *change* the navbar?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code after appending HTML code using DOM:

`$("div[data-role='navbar']").navbar();`

Comment: if you are using <nav> tag, it would be $("nav[data-role='navbar']").navbar();